# Material node - increase saturation one color?

Tags: materials, node-editor, color

How can you increase the saturation of **one** or two colors using nodes? I would like to increase the saturation of blue(s) and also the orange just a bit. This is in a material using nodes.
Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by this question? Do you have a desaturated texture image that you want to color Blue & Orange, or do you have a Full color texture image that you wish to isolate the Blue's & Oranges within, but desaturate all the rest?

Comment: Can you post your .blend and/or images?

Comment: Thanks, I am looking to enhance an image texture (that is actually a movie).  And I want to increase saturation but I am wondering if you can do it only on one or maybe a range of colors?

Comment: Probably easier to edit the texture itself, there aren't really any shader tools that can operate on individual color ranges, or isolate a color. Blender compositor can do the editing though, the color balance and keying nodes have some functions that aren't available as shaders that can do this.

Comment: Thanks (would have upvoted if I could). Too bad these nodes are not available as material nodes. Out of curiosity, do you know reason they are not?

Answer (score 3):

you can separate by adding a math node, setting it to greater, and and add the solid color you want in the bottom input. Put your image texture in the top input and this will separate your image into black and white anywhere were there was blue (or any color you choose) will be black and the rest will be white. you can take the output of this node and put it into the saturation of a Hue/Saturation node. If you want to control the amount of saturation just put a math node between the Greater Than node and the Hue/Saturation node. I hope this helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a second texture that has only the parts you want highlighted, and have the rest be alpha. It would be easy to increase that second textures saturation in Blender, possibly giving you the needed effect when mixed with the first.

Comment: Thanks, that would probably work but seems like alot of work as the texture is a movie. Anyways, I am mostly poking around learning and experimenting with the Blender suite.